# Create numerous lines in Simple Features from list of coordinates in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to detect whether pairs of objects (trees) are separated by roads or lie on the same side of them. I have downloaded my road network and think I more or less understand how to use `st_intersects`. So all I am missing are line segments between the pairs of trees I am considering in order to test intersections with the roads..

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to create lines between my objects. I have a large number of pairs (300K+), so must be able to do this programmatically, whereas all the examples I am finding seem to be "hand coded".

Suppose the following two matrices, containing the coordinates of the "origin" and "destination" of each pair.

```
    orig = matrix(runif(20),ncol=2)
    dest = matrix(runif(20),ncol=2)
```

In this example, I need to create 10 lines: one between `orig[1,]` and `dest[1,]`, another (distinct) one between `orig[2,]` and `dest[2,]`, etc. My understanding is that I should be using `st_multilinestring`, but I cannot figure out how to formulate the call. Typically, I either end up with "XYZM" points, or with a multi-segment line starting at `orig[1,]` and terminating at `dest[10,]` after going through all other coordinates. And when it is not one of these outcomes, it is a whole host of errors.

Is `st_multilinestring` what I should be using and if so, how does one do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over rows of your origin and destination matrices using `lapply` and create a vector of LINESTRING objects:

```
> lines = do.call(st_sfc,
              lapply(
                1:nrow(orig),
                function(i){
                   st_linestring(
                      matrix(
                        c(orig[i,],dest[i,]), ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
                   )
                }
               )
              )
```

This gives you this:

```
> lines
Geometry set for 10 features 
geometry type:  LINESTRING
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0.06157865 ymin: 0.007712881 xmax: 0.967166 ymax: 0.9864812
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
First 5 geometries:
LINESTRING (0.6646269 0.1545195, 0.8333102 0.40...
LINESTRING (0.5588124 0.5166538, 0.3213998 0.08...
LINESTRING (0.06157865 0.6138778, 0.06212246 0....
LINESTRING (0.202455 0.4883115, 0.5569435 0.986...
LINESTRING (0.3120373 0.8189916, 0.8499419 0.73...
```

Let's check we got all that the right way round. Where's the fourth line come from and going to?

```
> orig[4,]
[1] 0.2024550 0.4883115
> dest[4,]
[1] 0.5569435 0.9864812
```

which looks like the coordinates in the fourth LINESTRING output.

You can then `st_intersects` this with another set of features and see which of these cross them.

(You might also need to add the coordinate system to them...)

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!! And on top of that, `lapply` means I can `parlapply` if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to construct the `sfc` / `sf` object using `library(sfheaders)`

```
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)

## If you add a pseudo-id column
orig <- cbind( orig, 1:nrow( orig ) )
dest <- cbind( dest, 1:nrow( dest ) )

## you can bind these matrices together
m <- rbind( orig, dest )

## set the order by the 'id' column
m <- m[ order( m[,3] ), ]

## then use `sfheaders` to create your linestrings

sfc <- sfheaders::sfc_linestring(
  obj = m
  , linestring_id = 3 ## 3rd column
)

sfc

# Geometry set for 10 features 
# geometry type:  LINESTRING
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 0.01952919 ymin: 0.04603703 xmax: 0.9172785 ymax: 0.9516615
# epsg (SRID):    NA
# proj4string:    NA
# First 5 geometries:
# LINESTRING (0.7636528 0.2465392, 0.05899529 0.7...
# LINESTRING (0.6435893 0.9158161, 0.01952919 0.1...
# LINESTRING (0.05632407 0.3106372, 0.03306822 0....
# LINESTRING (0.1978259 0.07432209, 0.2907429 0.0...
# LINESTRING (0.1658199 0.6436758, 0.1407145 0.75...
```